# Context sensitive app for iPhone

Tags: iphone

For something like the Notes or Reminders on the iPhone, Apple makes the app look like a yellow sheet of notepad paper, or a white sheet of notepad paper.  I was wondering the basic premise on how someone goes about that.

For the Reminders app, I'm guessing they just use that off-white color for the background of the tableViewCell, and have that double red line on each TableViewCell on the LHS that makes it look like a sheet of school paper.

For the Notes app, no clue.  Any thoughts on either of these?  I kind of wanted a rough idea of how hard it is to make something like this.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's all about background images and custom fonts. That is all.

Comment: What is the 'context sensitive' part of your question? It sounds like you're just asking about how to draw content that looks like a sheet of paper. Is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Notes application for the iPhone pretty much is just a background image of a notepad with lines that is static, doesn't move and isn't created with rows or anything.  Above that is a layer of a textview that contains your words.  They use the image below already spaced to what they know the height of the rows are for a UITextView.